# wamp server installed in other then C drive

Tags: php, wamp

My windows 7 is installed in drive F and wamp also in that partition.

Now when I start wamp server its color remains 'red' which should be `green` if started correctly.

In case you install wamp in a partition other than C:\,I know I need to modify something. I forgot what.

I appreciate if some one can help me to get started with this.

Currently, it gives the error: `Unable to connect localhost`

Comment: There could be a number of reasons for Wamp's installation not to work.  Can you post the last few entries of your Apache error log?

Comment: do u have skype installed on your computer ?? sometimes skype takes the same port

Comment: always skype takes the same port;) but then it stays yellow, not red ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change it manually going to httpd.conf or default-server.conf and edit the DocumentRoot

on my machine, the file is in

```
C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.17\conf\httpd.conf
```

change DocumentRoot

```
 "c:/wamp/www/" to DocumentRoot "F:/wamp/www/" (line 178)
```

Comment: There were previously installed wamp source file in same folder. removed it and installed again. works fine now

Comment: @AcelasiEu what if i need to use multiple DocumentRoot, I have a windows server and I want to use all drives for DocumentRoot like : `MY_SERVER_IP/drv_c` for root of drive C: and `MY_SERVER_IP/drv_d` for root of drive D:, is that possible ?

Answer (score -1):

So Some times if you were start server is there in red color but that is not a problem , 
You can Try to this it may useful:

http:// here write 'localhost'.